# Generating the same random number in Java and Python

Tags: java, python

Is it possible to generate the same random number in python as in java if given the same seed

Explained in a more accurate way, Is it possible to use the linear congruential formula from java in Python?

Comment: If you could use Jython, I imagine you could hook into Java's random stuff directly and use it, doing this.

Comment: I would prefer to use pure python (from python.org's website) and somehow importing the java generator, if at all possible.

Comment: Anything that you have the formula for, you can code. I doubt you'll find something pre-built.

Comment: You mean CPython - nothing purer about it, just the reference implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this project? http://pypi.python.org/pypi/java-random

Comment: And once again Python makes me eat my words. Referring to my comment on the question.

Comment: This seems to do it, they even guessed what i needed it for. And it's working, thanks

Comment: @DelusionalLogic Generally an underscore means an implementation detail, so it's not something you want to access. [There is a function to set the seed](https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/java-random/blob/master/javarandom.py).

Comment: @Lattyware It was just repl taht didn't like it. It's working now that i created a real script for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```py
from jnius import autoclass

rand = autoclass('java.util.Random')()

rand.setSeed(12345)

print(rand.nextInt(50))
print(rand.nextInt(50))
print(rand.nextInt(50))
print(rand.nextInt(50))
```