# Get same sequence of shuffle on Kotlin and Python

Tags: python, numpy, kotlin, sequence, shuffle

I am `shuffle`ing a `list` in `Kotlin` & `Python`  using the same `seed` but i am getting different sequence. Cod on Python and Kotlin is as follows:

**Kotlin**

```
var trainInput = arrayListOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5)
val randomSeed = 1549786796.toLong()
trainInput.shuffle(Random(randomSeed))
```

**Output:**
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]

**Python:**

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
np.random.seed(1549786796)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

**Ouput:** [3 2 4 1 5]

Can anyone please point out how can I get the same sequence on both platforms?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I have also checked the library `java-random` (https://pypi.org/project/java-random/) suggested by Stef but this only generates the random number. I need to `shuffle` the list that generates the same sequence.

Comment: Java and numpy use different random number generators, so why do you expect them to yield the same results? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162798/generating-the-same-random-number-in-java-and-python and in particular https://pypi.org/project/java-random/

Comment: @Stef: I am working on `Machine Learning` problem, I want to compare the results and for that to be the same, input sequence should have to be same. I was wondering, if I can get the same sequence.

Comment: so `java-random` (see link above) should be your friend :)

Comment: @Stef: `java-random` only generates the random number. I want to `shuffle` the list that generates the same sequence.

Comment: Implement some simple random number generator (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062783/51685) in both languages and use it to power your Fisher-Yates shuffle implementation?

Comment: If you need the same input sequence, why not just make the input sequence the same? Forget about the randomisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining Stef and AKX answer produces the desired output. i.e., using `java-random` package on Python side to produce the same random number using same `seed` and then applying `Fisher-Yates` algorithm produces the same sequence.

```
import numpy as np
import javarandom as jrandom

r = jrandom.Random(1549786796)

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

def randomize(arr, n):
    # Start from the last element and swap one by one. We don't
    # need to run for the first element that's why i > 0
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        # Pick a random index from 0 to i
        j = r.nextInt(i + 1)

        # Swap arr[i] with the element at random index
        arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    return arr
```

**Output**: [7 5 1 4 6 2 3 8]

The above output is same on Kotlin and Python.

Thank you.

Comment: Glad we could help! :)